# 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricServiceManagementClient8'

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

i created client and calling my actor from the client , client is not able to communicate to the actor

even after using updated service fabric and runtime to latest getting error
I'm using vs2022 and service fabric runtime 10.xx, and SDK 7.X

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IFabricServiceManagementClient8'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{27309DB9-61A7-AE11-967A-BBFF7D5A5460}' failed due to the following error: No

Comment: this looks related the to service fabrics sdk. @teja-learn Have you gotten a solution to this yet?

Comment: I have the same issue with vs2022 and fabric sdk 10.1.1541. Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this exact same error message and I found that it was because the NuGet packages I use in my project were targetting a newer version of ServiceFabric than the one installed on my local machine.

Now I'm not sure which NuGets you're using for your Projects but take a look at the image below.

[image: Microsoft Service Fabric NuGet Structure]

At the top of you can see the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors (7.1.1541) NuGet package I use in my project.

If you drill down to Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting -> Microsft.ServiceFabric.Services -> Microsft.ServiceFabric (10.1.1541) that's where the error was coming from.

On my local machine I have ServiceFabric 10.0.1949. However, the Microsoft.ServiceFabric nugets  were targetting ServiceFabric 10.1.1541.

The fix was to rollback the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.XXXX nugets from 7.1.1541 to 7.0.1949. That way, the transitive 10.0.1949 nuget matched my local version of Service Fabric.

TL/DR: Rollback your project's Microsft.ServiceFabric.xxxx NuGet packages so that the transitive Microsft.ServiceFabric nuget package's version # matches your local Service Fabric version. For me, it was going from 7.1.1541 -> 7.0.1949.